# Do I need a service account for Google Directory API?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-directory-api

Bear with me, a total novice at APIs. I'm trying to build a web-app that allows my colleagues within the same domain to view a list of all other users in the domain after logging in. I'm attempting to use Google Directory API. Think of a roster, or org chart of sorts. I plan on using Django and python to build this.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/

I've created an OAuth 2.0 client ID, but I don't know if I need a service account to actually access the list of users. Additionally, I don't manage this domain, do I need to have the administrator grant priledges to this service account?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a service account, the account still has to "act" like a user on the domain, and that user has to have privileges to whatever scope you're using. If you can get the domain admin to give you access to list users, ask him/her for the readonly scope(to imply the impossibility of your app damaging the site)

When you create a service account you'll get a key that will authorize you to act as an account on the domain.

I don't think that you *need* a service account, but it's a little easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't manage that domain you cannot get a list of users.

You would need authorization for that service account to use the relevant scope(s). If you can't do it yourself and can't get it done by the administrator then this conversation is over :(